# Show that there is a step function $h$ on $I$ and a measurable subset $F$ of $I$ for which $h= \psi$ on $F$ and $m(I-F) < \epsilon$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let I be closed and bounded interval and $\psi$ a simple function defined on I. Let $\epsilon>0$. Show that there is a step function $h$ on $I$ and a measurable subset $F$ of $I$ for which $h= \psi$ on $F$ and $m(I-F) < \epsilon$. please any idea i am truly struggling with this problem, thanks, just ideas i do not want it to be solve.

i am looking for where to start ok thanks

Comment: Can you do it in case of $\psi (x) = 1_A$ for a measurable set $A$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint :**

Let $\psi=\boldsymbol 1_A$ where $A\subset I$ is a measurable set. By [Lusin theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lusin%27s_theorem), if $\varepsilon>0$, there is an $F\subset I$ such that $m(I-F)<\varepsilon$ and $\psi|_F$ is continuous. Then $\psi|_F=0$ or $\psi|_F=1$, which is a simple function.

I let you conclude if $\psi=\sum_{i=1}^n a_i\boldsymbol 1_{A_i}$.

Comment: In Royden Lusin thm is after this section, can you give an alternative proof? I got something but I want to verify.

Comment: @RichardClare: Please, post your answer :-)

Comment: I posted my answer, please verify below.

Comment: I guess my problem is different, its a step function not a simple function.

Comment: Step functions are defined on intervals, how do you make sure $\psi$ takes constant values on intervals.

Comment: @Beginner: should be replaced by simple function. I corrected it, tks for pointing out the typo.

Comment: Yes, but still, this question asks us to give a step function, not a simple funciton.

Answer (score 3):

Since $I$ has finite measure, exists $O = \bigcup (a_n,b_n)$ such that $m(O\setminus I) + m(I\setminus O) < \epsilon$. Take $F= O\bigcap I$ then is a subset of $I$ with $m(I\setminus F) = m(I\cap O^c) < \epsilon$. Now define

$$h(x) = 1_{E\cap F}(x) = 1_{E}(x), x \in F$$[image]

Comment: Maybe I didn't follow correctly, but the question the OP posted is problem 17 of chapter 3 within Royden's-Fitzpatrick's book (4th Ed.) -- the very next problem after the problem you posted a solution for above. I'm working out of this book currently, and I have a hint and a solution for problem 17 of Chapter 3 that follow's the structure of the book (as in I used only what was given up to section 3.2). I can post the hint or the solution if you would like, unless you have a solution to problem 17 already? Apologies for commenting since everything above is from years ago.

Comment: This doesn't answer OP's question and even the answer to the question 16 you posted is wrong.